# I am getting unusual object reference codes and null values when I initialise a constructor

Tags: java, class, arraylist, null, instance

I have a couple of questions about how class instances are set up. If I have an object constructor as follows:

```
Object(String newName, ArrayList<Person> newPersonList){
name=newName;
personList=newPersonList;
System.out.println(personList);}
```

which is then assigned to a person as a method in the `Object` class:

```
matchPersonToObject(Person person){
this.matchedPerson=person;
person.addToObjects(this); //do I need to add the full project.domain address in here?
   //Because if so it will only let me put the class `Person` in rather than an instance `person` 
}

//in the person class:
addToObjects(Object obj){
this.objectList.add(obj);
System.out.println(objectList);
}
```

when I then initialise this as follows:

```
Person chris=new Person("Chris");
Object obj1=new Object("thing",new ArrayList<Person>(Arrays.asList(chris)))
```

it gives an output of:

```
[project.domain.Person@1a40fff] //personList in object constructor
[Object - null] //objectList once person has been matched to it
```

My two questions are
a) what is that hexidecimal code that is being give to my person instance? Why does it not just display [project.domain.chris]?
b)When I add the object to the objectList, why is this registering as null? Have I initialised the ArrayList correctly?

Comment: Look into the `toString()` method. Don't name your class `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

First: Never name your classes with reserved words of languague you are using, e.g. avoid create classes with names like Vector, Long, etc... generates confuse in your code.

Second: he hexidecimal code you are looking at is the hash code of your class Person, overwrite the method toString() os Person class.

```
public String toString() {
    return <anything_you_want> + name;
}
```

it's possible a bad package importation because you have a class with Name object and compiler doesn't recognize your class, java.lang.Object is different of your Object class.